# How do I change the size of a seaborn tsplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

[Seaborn's `tsplot`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html) does not offer a `size` option like some of the other plot types (e.g., `lmplot`). I understand that this is due to `tsplot` being an axis-level function and `lmplot`, for example, being a figure-level function.

**Question:**

I really just want a simple `tsplot` and set the size of the figure like I would do in `lmplot`. How can I do that?

**What I've tried:**

This probably means I have to combine a `FacetGrid` (with just one facet) with my `tsplot`. There does not seem to be any straightforward example online.

When I do:

```
sns.tsplot(data = data, time = "index", value = "score", unit = "mode", condition = "mode")
```

I get a nice plot, with the condition properly colored, just with the wrong size:

[image]

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data, size = 10)
grid.map(sns.tsplot, data = data, time = "index", value = "score", unit = "mode", condition = "mode")
```

I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tsplot` just plots onto the currently active matplotlib axes, unless you specify one to the `ax` parameter. That means any of the various ways to control the figure size in matplotlib apply. My preferred approach would be:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
sns.tsplot(..., ax=ax)
```

It's not strictly necessary to specify the `ax` here, but probably good form.